# Excel, look values in table where both rows and columns are ranges

Tags: excel, range, conditional-statements

I apologise if the title is confusing. it's hard for me to summarise this issue in one sentence.

I'm trying to automate some spreadsheets, but sadly using VBA is not an option (most people here get confused by them and end up avoiding those spreadsheets).

The problem: I have rows in one sheet with data for velocity and angle and I'm trying to get a value from this other table based on those parameters.
The issue is that this other table is based in ranges of values for both columns and rows.

`A        B      C       D        E
1                  0     1-30   31-60    61-90
2       0 to 1     10     20      20      30
3      1.1 to 2    10     20      30      30
4      2.1 to 3    20     30      30      40
5        '>3       30     40      40      40`

Where column A is velocity range, Row 1 is angle range

So for example if I have a velocity of 1.5 m/s with an angle of 40°, I want to be able to get the result of 30.

My best idea is to create auxiliary or helper columns to indicate which velocity and angle range they belong to and then use a VLOOKUP MATCH combo.

Even though it's a simple solution, I just wanted to know if there is a more elegant solution available that comes to mind or if you think this is already elegant enough.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you change the lookup table a little.  If you remove the ranges and just put the minimum ie in A `0`,`1.1`,`2.1`,`3.1` and the same with row 1 `0`,`1`,`31`,`61` then a simple index/match/match will do it.

Answer (score 0):

As Scott mentioned, using ranges as titles makes it difficult.
If you simply put in the minimums instead youcan make the following:

```
       A         B      C       D        E        F        G          H   
1                0      1       31      61                 Velocity   1.5
2      0         10     20      20      30                 Angle      40
3      1.1       10     20      30      30                 Result     30
4      2.1       20     30      30      40
5      3.1       30     40      40      40
```

Where H1 and H2 are your input cells.

H3 gives you the result with: `=INDEX(B2:E5,MATCH(H1,A2:A5,1),MATCH(H2,B1:E1,1))`